# How "exotic" are non-local directly irreducible modular group algebras?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, representation-theory, direct-product, group-rings

Let $G$ be a finite group and $R = \Bbb F_{p^k} G$ a modular group algebra ($p$ divides $|G|$). I would like to know when $R$ is a directly indecomposable ring. It is quite well-known that $R$ is local iff $G$ is a $p$-group, but a finite noncommutative ring can, of course, have nontrivial idempotents without any of them being central.

I have a suspicion that Brauer's three theorems or related results might give a description of such $G$'s, or some strong properties of them (e.g. related to factorization of $|G|$), but I am not familiar with their modus operandi. For instance, if the $p$-Sylow is normal, then the first theorem (from what I'm reading on Wikipedia) is a tautology.

H. Meyer [computed](https://epub.uni-bayreuth.de/510/1/Meyer_idemsymchar2.pdf) the central idempotents for $\Bbb F_2 S_n$, $n \le 54$, and apparently $\Bbb F_2 S_4$ has a single block (the expressions on pp. 3–5 have no $|_4$).

Comment: "Single block" amounts to $R/J(R)$ being a simple ring?

Comment: @rschwieb No, rather $R$ should not be expressible as $R_1 \times R_2$ for nontrivial $R_i$. Then $R/J(R)$ is not necessarily a matrix ring.

Comment: In books I have read "block" usually refers to ring summands of $R/J(R)$, but I'll take it for granted that you're asking about indecomposability of $R$ itself.

Comment: Maybe you already know this, but If $G$ has any nontrivial normal subgroup $H$ with $|H|$ coprime to $p$, then you can show $e=(\sum_{h\in H}h)/|H|$ is a nontrivial central idempotent.

Comment: I'm a zero divisor when it comes to rep. theory (read "not in the field"), so the term might indeed not be standard. I've read it on [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_representation_theory#Blocks_and_the_structure_of_the_group_algebra) and in a few papers (M.J.Collins 1998, W.F.Reynolds 1966 in a generalized context). For the averaging over a normal $p'$-subgroup, thanks! It's a good step forward but I fear quite broad for my applications. Is it at least reasonable to expect one-block group algebras of non-$p$-groups to be "rare"?

Comment: I think it's fair to ask "how _exotic_ are irreducible modular group algebras (aside from the case when $G$ is a $p$-group)?"

Comment: Such rings are always quasi-Frobenius, and i'm kind of surprised how little there seems to be on irreducible QF rings.  I found [this](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Omar-Almallah-2/publication/333304143_A_classification_of_indecomposable_Quasi-Frobenius_rings_I/links/60fbcbcc169a1a0103b22513/A-classification-of-indecomposable-Quasi-Frobenius-rings-I.pdf) but it only covers a generalization of _prime_ QF rings, and (according to my now-deleted answer) the modular rings you're concerned with are not prime...

Comment: Perhaps general structure theory is not the way to go. representation theory knows a lot about $kG$ so I wouldn't be surprised if there's already a strong statement about when its irreducible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A necessary condition (as pointed out in comments by @rschwieb) is that $G$ has no nontrivial normal subgroup of order coprime to $p$.

Theorem 2.1 of

*Fong, P.; Gaschütz, W.*, [**A note on the modular representations of solvable groups**](https://doi.org/10.1515/crll.1961.208.73), J. Reine Angew. Math. 208, 73-78 (1961). [ZBL0100.25801](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0100.25801).

states that any solvable finite group satisfying this condition has only one $p$-block. This covers the case of $S_4$ in characteristic $2$.

The condition of solvability was weakened to being [$p$-constrained](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-constrained_group) by Cossey and Gaschütz in Theorem 1 of

*Cossey, John; Gaschütz, Wolfgang*, A note on blocks, Proc. 2nd internat. Conf. Theory of Groups, Canberra 1973, Lect. Notes Math. 372, 238-240 (1974). [ZBL0295.20015](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0295.20015).

(@rschwieb discovered this result in Blackburn and Huppert's *Finite Groups II*.)

Given that people were proving results like this in the 1970s I'm guessing that there's no simple necessary and sufficient condition for general finite groups. Being $p$-constrained is not a necessary condition, as I used GAP to check sporadic simple groups (which are never $p$-constrained if their order is divisible by $p$), and in characteristic $2$ the Mathieu groups $M_{22}$ and $M_{24}$ each have only one block.

Comment: The resource I found for irreducible group-rings was [Finite groups II](https://books.google.com/books?id=t2zpCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA529&lpg=PA529&dq=%22indecomposable+group+ring%22&source=bl&ots=BdqanuZwpO&sig=ACfU3U0yPD_hZj3Kcr_PrZVm7yBYsY_u8Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjUlc_fp9mCAxVbD1kFHX4dBgYQ6AF6BAgKEAM#v=onepage&q=%22indecomposable%20group%20ring%22&f=false) which I think is saying something very similar in section 13.

Comment: @rschwieb Ah, nice! That contains a 1973 theorem of Cossey and Gaschütz that is the same result as in Navarro's book, but with a more general condition ([$p$-constrained](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-constrained_group)) than $p$-solvable. Given that people were proving results like this in the 1970s I'm guessing that there's no simple necessary and sufficient condition for general finite groups.

Comment: There are a couple of examples for $p=2$ among sporadic simple groups (which are not $p$-constrained): the Mathieu groups $M_{22}$ and $M_{24}$ each have only one $2$-block, according to GAP. So the condition of Cossey and Gaschütz is sufficient but not necessary.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include all of this new information.

Comment: Were the algebras over the rest of the Mathieu groups mentioned? It's really strange if just those two had this property...

Comment: @rschwieb I think those are the only finite simple groups (apart from cyclic groups of prime order) that have only one block in any characteristic. Of the Mathieu sporadic simple groups in characteristic $2$, $M_{11}$ has three blocks, $M_{12}$ has two blocks, and $M_{23}$ has three blocks. If I'd had to guess beforehand, I would have expected the larger groups to have more blocks, but I suppose the numbers are small.

Comment: So these algebras are not really exotic at all. rschwieb and Jeremy Rickard, thank you very much!

Comment: @Amateur_Algebraist Not exotic? At the moment we only have the local ones and these two sporadic groups as examples... seems like pretty slim pickings at the moment!

Comment: @rschwieb We have all the $p$-constrained ones as well.

Comment: @JeremyRickard $p$-constrained groups satisfying the additional condition on normal subgroups, that is?  I hadn't appreciated that you mentioned the sporadic group examples were _not_ p-constrained.  I guess solvable groups (and hence p-constrained) are not a small class, but if set aside like the $p$-groups then it sounds like it begins to become challenging to find other 1-block examples

Comment: Can GAP help figure out what the Jacobson radical of $F_2[S_4]$ looks like?  Beyond the nilpotent ideal generated by $(\sum_{g\in S_4}g)$ I'm not sure what there is.  I'm hoping to know what $R/J(R)$ looks like.

Comment: @rschwieb $R/J(R)\cong\mathbb{F}_2\times M_2(\mathbb{F}_2)$. GAP can answer questions like this, but the representation theory of small groups like this is very well understood, so most questions you might have can probably be answered without resorting to a computer.

Comment: @JeremyRickard Oh, I'm sure. I was assuming you'd tell me the ones you knew if GAP didn't :)  I've often wanted to know all those secrets but time does not permit :(

Comment: @rschwieb GAP has a large library of character tables. While looking at the manual to work out how to search for examples with one block, I discovered that they give as an example looking for simple groups with only one block (and get the same answer as me!) There are 344 examples $(G,p)$ where $G$ is a group that is not $p$-solvable, whose character table is in the library, and which only has one $p$-block. I haven't yet thought of an easy way to tell how many of these are $p$-constrained.

Answer (score 0):

There exists a full classification in terms of group properties of $G$ (over $\overline{\Bbb F_p}$). Can the *principal* block split when passing to the algebraic closure..?

*Harris, M. E.,* **[On the $p$-deficiency class of a finite group](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869385901942)**, J. Algebra **94**:2, 411–424 (1985) (bracketed comments mine):

> **Theorem 1.** Let G be an arbitrary finite group. Then:
>
> (a) if $p$ is an odd prime integer, then $B_0(G)$ *[the principal block]* is the only $p$-block of $G$ if and only if $F^*(G)$ *[the generalized Fitting subgroup]* $= O_p(G)$ *[the $p$-core of $G$]*; and
>
> (b) $B_0(G)$ is the only $2$-block of $G$ if and only if (i) $O_{2'}(G) = 1$ and
> (ii) all components of $G$ are of type $M_{22}$ or $M_{24}$.

(I found the article in references of *Liu, Y.; Willems, W.,* **[Lie-type-like groups](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S002186931500472X)**, J. Algebra **447**, 432–444 (2016).)

---

In his latter comment about **simple** groups, @JeremyRickard likely alludes to this theorem in Harris's paper (by the comment after **Definition 1**, $p$-deficiency class $0$ is equivalent to having a single $p$-block):

> **Theorem 4.** (a) $M_{22}$ and $M_{24}$ are the only finite simple groups of $2$-deficiency class $0$.

and the paper *Brockhaus, P.; Michler, G. O.*, **[Finite simple groups of Lie type have non-principal $p$-blocks, $p \not = 2$](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869385902066)**, J. Algebra **94**:1, 113–125 (1985) which is used there.

If I understood the definitions of $F^*$ and $O_p$ correctly, **Theorem 1** (a) implies that there cannot be simple groups with one $p$-block in characteristic $p > 2$.