# Extension of scalars in single-block group algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification, representation-theory, group-rings

The question in the title is a follow-up for [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4811711/) one. I am now specifically interested in **simple** groups, and the results of papers I found (by [Harris](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869385901942), and [Brockhaus and Michler](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869385902066)) imply that

> If $G$ is a finite non-Abelian simple group, and $\overline{\Bbb F_p} G$ only has a single block, then $p = 2$ and $G$ is either $M_{22}$ or $M_{24}$.

The case $p = 2$ is stated in Harris Theorem 4(a) in plain words, and for $p > 2$ it is (or seems to be...) a consequence of his Theorem 1(a). (The proof depends on the results of Brockhaus and Michler, who have done the Lie type case.)

---

However all of this is proven over the *algebraic closure* of a finite field, rather than the finite field itself (which I am interested in). For semisimple group algebras, the splitting of a block in a field extension is commonplace, however the *principal* block is always 1-dimensional and thus can't split. Can it split in the modular setup above? In other words,

> **"Problem."** Let $k = \Bbb F_{p^m}$, $K = \overline{k}$, $G$ a finite simple group. Prove that if $kG$ has only the principal block, then the same is true of $KG$.

*My attempt* (that does not use simplicity of $G$). By Lemma 13.2 in Blackburn and Huppert *Finite groups II*, p. 185, for an irreducible $FG$-module "being in the principal block" is equivalent to "being annihilated by $(\sum\limits_{g \in C} g) - |C|$ for all conjugacy classes $C$" (this Condition is independent of properties of $F$).
We have $KG \cong K \otimes_k kG$, and presumably *any irreducible $KG$-module $M$ is <strike>a constituent</strike> (**Edit 14 Jan 2024: isomorphic to a submodule**) of $K \otimes_k \mu$ for some irreducible $kG$-module $\mu$* (the most phony point — is this still true in the modular case?) Then if $M$ fell outside the principal block of $KG$, so would $\mu$ in $kG$ by the above Condition. "$\square$"

(In 12.6, the blocks are defined for arbitrary fields $F$ of positive characteristic.)

My questions: 1) Is this "argument" reasonable, especially the part in italics? How to prove it? 2) If it isn't, is the "problem" statement even true?

Answer (score 0):

From the same book by Blackburn and Huppert, p. 21:

> **Theorem 1.18a).** Let $L/K$ be a Galois extension and $V$ an irreducible $LG$-module. Then there exists an irreducible $KG$-module $W$ s.t. $V$ is isomorphic to a *direct summand* of $W \otimes_K L$. Furthermore, $W$ is unique up to isomorphism.

This is proved by reducing to the semisimple part.

---

The argument can be made sound if one notes that every irreducible (or even just indecomposable) module lies in some block, and every block contains some irreducible module — see Definition 12.6.